# How to add post featured image url to inline background url()?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'd like to get a post's featured image and use it in the style="background: url()" of the post. I thought this would do it, but alas I was wrong because this outputs the whole (img src=""> stuff.

```
<div style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
) !important;">adasdasdasd </div>
```

I tried get_post_thumbnail but don't think I have the format right.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to retrieve the src attribute of the thumbnail:

```
$thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_post_thumbnail_id('thumbnail'));
```

`$thumb_src` is then an array containg the url, width and height of the thumbnail image.  So something like...

```
<div style="background: url(<?php echo $thumb_src[0];?>
) !important;">adasdasdasd </div>
```

should work.